# How to select highest values in each column and print row name in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose we have a dataframe like this:

```
       value_1 value_2 value_3
Name_1  5       10      11
Name_2  1       2       1
Name_3  9       8       7
```

I want to subset the data frame so that I have the highest values with the row names. I.e. something like:

```
Name_1 Name_2 Name_3
11     2      9
```

Does anyone know how to do this, e.g. something that could contain `max(df$value_1)`?

Comment: Your last comment seems to contradict the earlier explanation.  Do you want the max for each row, or for each column?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
df <- data.frame(value_1 = c(5, 1, 9),
                 value_2 = c(10, 2, 8), 
                 value_3 = c(11, 1, 7))
rownames(df) <- c("Name_1", "Name_2", "Name_3")

apply(df[, 1:3], 1, max)

> Name_1 Name_2 Name_3 
>     11      2      9
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~value_1, ~value_2, ~value_3,
 5,       10,      11,
1,       2,       1,
9,       8,      7) %>% 
  as.data.frame()


rownames(df)<- c("name_1","name_2","name_3")

df2 <- df %>% 
   transpose() %>% 
  simplify_all() %>% 
  map_dfc(max) %>% 
  setNames(rownames(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized option in `base R` is `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, df)
#[1] 11  2  9
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(value_1 = c(5, 1, 9), value_2 = c(10, 2, 8), value_3 = c(11, 
1, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Name_1", "Name_2", 
"Name_3"))
```